# String manupulation by adding spaces (' ') upto length 20

Tags: c, string

I have a function written in avr gcc for atmega128 to add extra spaces to string if the length of string is less than 20 to display it in LCD. When I don't use this function continuously then the output is as expected but when I use it continuously and display output, only the last string is displayed. What causes this kind of problem ?

```
void parse(uint8_t* str, uint8_t endlen, uint8_t charac)
{
    //str is string passed, charac is the fill character, endlen is length of string passed
    uint8_t len = 0;    // length count start from 0    

    while(str[len] != '\0') {
        len++;      
    }
    while(len < endlen){
        str[len] = charac;
        len++;
    }
    str[endlen] = '\0';
}
```

When I call this program as

```
int main(void){
    uint8_t str1[20] = "0123456789";
    uint8_t str2[20] = "abcdefghij0123456789";

    parse(str1, 20, ' ');           
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", str1);
    parse(str2, 20, ' ');
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", str2);
    while(1);
}
```

Output is :

0123456789

abcdefghij0123456789

But when I call the function as

```
int main(void){
    uint8_t str1[20] = "0123456789";
    uint8_t str2[20] = "abcdefghij0123456789";

    parse(str1, 20, ' ');           
    parse(str2, 20, ' ');
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", str1);
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", str2);
    while(1);
}
```

Output is:

abcdefghij0123456789

Comment: And when you add a sleep between fprintf() commands ?

Comment: What is the target of your stderr stream? If the stream uses a limited buffer for example, which takes some time to clear (stream data out to display), calling the fprintf() in direct succession could cause the buffer contents from the first call to be overwritten by the second one.

Comment: The target of stderr is uart1 tx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write `'\0'` to element 20 (that does not exist) of the string.
This is undefined behavior.

Comment: The string length is 20 (0:19) and the compiler automatically declares  length 21 with '\0' to the last element. Isn't that how its supposed to be ?

Comment: @sujan_014 you declared no string. you declared a character array of length 20. and that is exactly that your compiler creates.